# Laravel migration can't create relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables, users and friend_requests, and I want to create foreign key, but getting following error.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `larasocial`.`#sql-1710_1f5` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `friend_requests` add constraint `friend_requests_sender_id_foreign` foreign key (`sender_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete cascade on update cascade)

**users migration file**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string("name", 255);
            $table->string("surname", 255);
            $table->string("email", 255);
            $table->string("password", 255);
            $table->date("birthday");
            $table->string("gender", 255);
            $table->string("photo", 255);
            $table->integer("recover_code")->default(0);
            $table->boolean("confirmed")->default(false);
            $table->dateTime("last_visit");
            $table->date("created_at");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

**friend_requests migration file**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateFriendRequestsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('friend_requests', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->integer("sender_id");
            $table->integer("accepter_id");

            $table->foreign("sender_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade")->onUpdate("cascade");
            $table->foreign("accepter_id")->references("id")->on("users")->onDelete("cascade")->onUpdate("cascade");
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('friend_requests');
    }
}
```

I have already tried methods of other similar problems, but they are not solving my problem.

Comment: Use same data type. Your users.id is big integer, and your friends_requests.sender_id uses integer.

Comment: @EliasSoares Thank you for your answer.The problem is solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The foreign key column need to be the same data type as the reference it's pointing to. Since your user id is big integer, your reference fields must also be big integers.

Edit for future viewers:

- change both columns to `unsignedBigInteger`

Comment: Thank you, also added ->unsigned().

Comment: ->unsigned() in `bigInteger`is same that `unsignedBigInteger`